# Postsharp MethodInterceptionAspect attribute throws EntrypointNotFoundException

Tags: c#, postsharp, aop

I have recently updated PostSharp to v4.1.13 and I have started receiving this error when I try to build my solution:

The custom attribute 'True.Kentico.Caching.KenticoCacheAttribute' constructor threw the exception EntryPointNotFoundException: Entry point was not found.

This attribute implements caching, and has worked  before, so I'm wondering what would be the cause of it breaking. I am using this attribute in other assemblies referencing the aspect's containing assembly, and I get that error in there as well.

The following is the code for the attribute. Apologies, it contains a number of constructors.

```
[Serializable]
public class KenticoCacheAttribute : MethodInterceptionAspect
{
    public int CacheMinutes { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// the string value of the cache dependency key. If it uses parameters from the method, include a {0} to format with the method parameter 
    /// </summary>
    public string CacheDependency { get; set; }
    public string[] CacheDependencyStrings { get; set; }

    public KenticoCacheDependencyObtainFrom ObtainCacheDependencyFrom { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// whether caching is enabled - default from app settings
    /// </summary>
    public bool CacheEnabled { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// this is the index of the parameter that will be used to format the cachedependency, if required 
    /// </summary>
    public int CacheDependencyParameterIndex { get; set; }


    public string CacheDependencyObjectProperty { get; set; }

    private string _methodName;

    /// <summary>
    /// initializes the cache attribute to use a static dependency
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cacheDependency"></param>
    public KenticoCacheAttribute(string cacheDependency)
    {
        CacheMinutes = EngineContext.Current.Resolve<AppSettings>().Cache.TTL.GlobalSetting;
        CacheEnabled = !EngineContext.Current.Resolve<AppSettings>().Cache.IgnoreCache;
        CacheDependencyParameterIndex = -1;
        CacheDependency = cacheDependency;
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(cacheDependency))
            ObtainCacheDependencyFrom = KenticoCacheDependencyObtainFrom.NoDependency;
        else
        {

            ObtainCacheDependencyFrom = KenticoCacheDependencyObtainFrom.Static;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// initializes the cache attribute to use a static dependency using multiple depndencies
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cacheDependencystrings">an array of strings</param>
    public KenticoCacheAttribute(string[] cacheDependencystrings)
    {
        CacheMinutes = EngineContext.Current.Resolve<AppSettings>().Cache.TTL.GlobalSetting;
        CacheEnabled = !EngineContext.Current.Resolve<AppSettings>().Cache.IgnoreCache;
        CacheDependencyParameterIndex = -1;
        CacheDependencyStrings = cacheDependencystrings;
        ObtainCacheDependencyFrom = KenticoCacheDependencyObtainFrom.MultipleDependenciesStatic;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// initializes the cache attribute to take the dependency from the input parameter 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cacheDependency">the static string to be used for the cache dependency. you may include {CurrentSiteName} to be replaced with the current site name, and {0} to be replaced with the value passed in as one of the method parameters</param>
    /// <param name="cacheDependencyParameterIndex">the index of the parameter in the method parameters that will be used to create the cache dependency key</param>
    public KenticoCacheAttribute(string cacheDependency, int cacheDependencyParameterIndex)
    {
        CacheMinutes = EngineContext.Current.Resolve<AppSettings>().Cache.TTL.GlobalSetting;
        CacheEnabled = !EngineContext.Current.Resolve<AppSettings>().Cache.IgnoreCache;
        CacheDependencyParameterIndex = cacheDependencyParameterIndex;
        CacheDependency = cacheDependency;
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(cacheDependency))
        {

            ObtainCacheDependencyFrom = KenticoCacheDependencyObtainFrom.MultipleDependenciesFromParameter;
        }
        else
        {

            ObtainCacheDependencyFrom = KenticoCacheDependencyObtainFrom.FromMethodParameter;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// initialize the cache attribute to obtain the cache dependency from the named property of the return object 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cacheDependency">the static string to be used for the cache dependency. you may include {CurrentSiteName} to be replaced with the current site name, and {0} to be replaced with the value in the named parameter </param>
    /// <param name="cacheDependencyObjectPropertyName">the name of the property of the return object that will be used to replace the placeholder in the static string to build the cache dependency string</param>
    public KenticoCacheAttribute(string cacheDependency, string cacheDependencyObjectPropertyName)
    {
        CacheMinutes = EngineContext.Current.Resolve<AppSettings>().Cache.TTL.GlobalSetting;
        CacheEnabled = !EngineContext.Current.Resolve<AppSettings>().Cache.IgnoreCache;
        CacheDependencyParameterIndex = -1;
        CacheDependency = cacheDependency;
        ObtainCacheDependencyFrom = KenticoCacheDependencyObtainFrom.FromReturnObject;
        CacheDependencyObjectProperty = cacheDependencyObjectPropertyName;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// initialize the cache attribute to obtain the cache dependency from the named property of the return object 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cacheDependency">the static string to be used for the cache dependency. you may include {CurrentSiteName} to be replaced with the current site name, and {0} to be replaced with the value in the named parameter </param>
    /// <param name="cacheDependencyParameterIndex"></param>
    /// <param name="cacheDependencyObjectPropertyName">the name of the property of the return object that will be used to replace the placeholder in the static string to build the cache dependency string</param>
    public KenticoCacheAttribute(string cacheDependency, int cacheDependencyParameterIndex, string cacheDependencyObjectPropertyName)
    {
        CacheMinutes = EngineContext.Current.Resolve<AppSettings>().Cache.TTL.GlobalSetting;
        CacheEnabled = !EngineContext.Current.Resolve<AppSettings>().Cache.IgnoreCache;
        CacheDependencyParameterIndex = cacheDependencyParameterIndex;
        CacheDependency = cacheDependency;
        ObtainCacheDependencyFrom = KenticoCacheDependencyObtainFrom.FromMethodParameterObjectProperty;
        CacheDependencyObjectProperty = cacheDependencyObjectPropertyName;
    }

    public override void CompileTimeInitialize(MethodBase method, AspectInfo aspectInfo)
    {
        _methodName = method.Name;
    }

    public override void OnInvoke(MethodInterceptionArgs args)
    {
        var methodInfo = args.Method as MethodInfo;
        if (methodInfo != null && (methodInfo.ReturnType != typeof(void) && CacheEnabled))
        {
            var cacheKey = BuildCacheKey(args.Arguments);

            var cacheSettings = new CacheSettings(CacheMinutes, cacheKey);
            var data = CacheHelper.Cache(cs => GetData(cs, args), cacheSettings);
            args.ReturnValue = data;
        }
        else
            base.OnInvoke(args);
    }

    private object GetData(CacheSettings cs, MethodInterceptionArgs args)
    {
        var data = args.Invoke(args.Arguments);

        // Checks whether data was loaded and whether the data should be cached (based on the CacheSettings)
        if ((data != null) && cs.Cached)
        {
            // Sets a cache dependency for the data
            // The data is removed from the cache if the objects represented by the dummy key are modified (all user objects in this case)
            var dependencyResolver = CacheDependencyFactory.GetDependecyFormatter(ObtainCacheDependencyFrom);

            var dependencyString = dependencyResolver.Format(new CacheDependencyFormatParameters()
            {
                CacheDependencyBase = CacheDependency,
                CacheDependencybaseString = CacheDependencyStrings,
                InputParameterIndex = CacheDependencyParameterIndex,
                ReturnParameterName = CacheDependencyObjectProperty,
                InputParameterData = args,
                ReturnParameterData = data
            });

            cs.CacheDependency = CacheHelper.GetCacheDependency(dependencyString);
        }



        return data;
    }

    private string BuildCacheKey(Arguments arguments)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(_methodName);
        foreach (var argument in arguments.ToArray())
        {
            sb.Append(argument == null ? "_" : argument.ToString());
        }
        sb.Append(String.Format("{0}_{1}", SiteContext.CurrentSiteName,
            SiteContext.CurrentSite.DefaultVisitorCulture));
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: How is EngineContext.Current initialized? Aspect constructors are executed as part of PostSharp process - it means on build time. The aspect is serialized then and deserialized on runtime. If EngineContext was initialized from the same assembly that contains KenticoCacheAttribute, then it could be available on build time. Please, in which version was your aspect working correctly?

Comment: Upon review, I'm not sure where it broke. EngineContext was being initialized at app_start of the web app, and the KenticoCache attribute was trying to resolve something from the enginecontext before this happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that the issue is with these lines of code in the constructors:

```
CacheMinutes = EngineContext.Current.Resolve<AppSettings>().Cache.TTL.GlobalSetting;
CacheEnabled = !EngineContext.Current.Resolve<AppSettings>().Cache.IgnoreCache;
```

When PostSharp runs, The dependencyInjection framework has not yet been initialised, so the execution fails. It's strange that it was working before, but hey. I moved this code into the OnInvoke method, which should only run when the DI Enginecontext has been initialised :

```
public override void OnInvoke(MethodInterceptionArgs args)
    {

        CacheMinutes = EngineContext.Current.Resolve<AppSettings>().Cache.TTL.GlobalSetting;
        CacheEnabled = !EngineContext.Current.Resolve<AppSettings>().Cache.IgnoreCache;
        var methodInfo = args.Method as MethodInfo;
......
```